# How to get checkbox value from strutcure in template (velocity)

Tags: java, checkbox, liferay, structure, velocity

I've a **structure** in **liferay** which has a checkbox into a `dynamic-element` tag (called **item_name_1**)
Now how can i read checkbox value in my template ?

**Structure**

```
<dynamic-element dataType="string" indexType="keyword" name="item_name_1" readOnly="false" repeatable="true" required="false" showLabel="true" type="text" width="small">
    <dynamic-element dataType="link-to-page" fieldNamespace="ddm" indexType="keyword" name="content_lnk" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" required="false" showLabel="true" type="ddm-link-to-page" width="small">
        <dynamic-element dataType="boolean" indexType="keyword" name="service_menustat" readOnly="true" repeatable="true" required="false" showLabel="true" type="checkbox" width="">
            <meta-data locale="fa_IR">
                <entry name="label">
                    <![CDATA[منو بصورت پیش فرض باز باشد]]>
                </entry>
                <entry name="predefinedValue">
                    <![CDATA[false]]>
                </entry>
                <entry name="tip">
                    <![CDATA[]]>
                </entry>
            </meta-data>
        </dynamic-element>
        <meta-data locale="fa_IR">
            <entry name="label">
                <![CDATA[اتصال به صفحه]]>
            </entry>
            <entry name="predefinedValue">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </entry>
            <entry name="tip">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </entry>
        </meta-data>
    </dynamic-element>
</dynamic-element>
```

also I tried to get specific checkbox in my template (velocity) using `$service_menustat.getData()` and `$service_menustat.data` and even `'$service_menustat'`

`$service_menustat` is not exist in template intellisense..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! problem was about `checkbox` which wrongly putted in second level of childs of **item_name1** ! so i made it to be the first level child of **item_name1** then i saw problem fixed.
new **structure** should be like this to solve mentioned problem.

```
<dynamic-element dataType="string" indexType="keyword" name="item_name_1" readOnly="false" repeatable="true" required="false" showLabel="true" type="text" width="small">
<dynamic-element dataType="boolean" indexType="keyword" name="service_menustat" readOnly="true" repeatable="false" required="false" showLabel="true" type="checkbox" width="">
    <meta-data locale="fa_IR">
        <entry name="label">
            <![CDATA[منو بصورت پیش فرض باز باشد]]>
        </entry>
        <entry name="predefinedValue">
            <![CDATA[false]]>
        </entry>
        <entry name="tip">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </entry>
    </meta-data>
</dynamic-element>
<dynamic-element dataType="link-to-page" fieldNamespace="ddm" indexType="keyword" name="content_lnk" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" required="false" showLabel="true" type="ddm-link-to-page" width="small">
    <meta-data locale="fa_IR">
        <entry name="label">
            <![CDATA[اتصال به صفحه]]>
        </entry>
        <entry name="predefinedValue">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </entry>
        <entry name="tip">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </entry>
    </meta-data>
</dynamic-element>
```

and i get it in **template** using

```
#foreach ($item_name1 in $item_name_1.getSiblings())
    <span>$item_name1.service_menustat.getData()<span>
#end
```